# how to connect to a sqlite db using sequel pro

Tags: sqlite

Hi I installed QLite Pro but Im unable to connect to a local SQLite file db how can I do this?

The fields to fill are:

```
Name:
Host: requeire
UserName:
PassWord:
Database:
Port:
```

Comment: The "Sequel" tag is not for the application "Sequel Pro".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the end I solved this by using the program [DB Browser for SQLite](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser), I also tried the Firefox plugin but this one is better.

Answer (score 12):

You can't! Sequel Pro is only for MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, i couldn't make it work.

So I downloaded this firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ which works fine.

Here's a small guide on how to open a sqlite database from a app in the iPhone simulator

> 1. Run your application on simulator (so that the database file will be copied to your application's documents folder (don't bother if you don't know exactly what it means))
> 2. Run the SQLite Manager plugin in Firefox (Tools -> SQLite Manager)
> 3. Open the database (You can find the file by navigating: /Libraries/ApplicationSupport/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/(*number)/Documents
>
> *number is some sequence of hexadecimal numbers identifying current application bundle - you must just find the proper folder (it will contain .app)
>
> It is also possible with database on device, but first you must download application's documents folder to some place on your computer. You can download the folder by going in Xcode -> Organizer, then select your Device and Summary Tab, then under the Applications list find your application, click the triangle |> to expand it, then click the arrow on the right to download the application's documents folder.

Source: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42573-browsing-sqlite3-database.html

Comment: Plugin has been deprecated.